# Quartz scheduler job get not executed repeatedly for every 5 minute

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have code to schedule a job to execute at every 5 minutes. The code is as follow

```
JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(ChieldJob.class).withIdentity(("job_"+sched_id+"_"+schd_name), "todaysJob")
                            .setJobData(chieldJobData).build();
```

The code to make trigger is as follow.

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(("trg_" + sched_id +"_"+schd_name), "todaysJob")
                            .startAt(new Date(row.get(field_Schd_Start_TS).longValue()))
                            .build();
trigger = trigger.getTriggerBuilder().withSchedule((ScheduleBuilder) SimpleScheduleBuilder.repeatMinutelyForever(5)).build();
```

Now I schedule a job by below code

```
context.getScheduler().scheduleJob(jobDetail,trigger);
```

Here the context is the object of JobExecutionContext, because, I am initiating this job from other job execution class. getScheduler() method will return the same scheduler instance from which the main job gets executed

The problem is, this job in "jobDetail" object is get executed only once, at a specified time, specified by ".startAt(new Date(row.get(field_Schd_Start_TS)" then it do not get executed at every 5 minutes.
**I am not able to find out why it does not get executed repeatedly.**

The nextFireTime is null, in the trigger. why? I am not able to find out this.
I make a small program in the main method to schedule job, here I see that, when the job gets executed, we get the JobExecutionContext object in that job, here I debug and see it contains the object of the trigger, which has nextFireTime set as expected.
**But that do not happen in actual implementaion of that code where I use.**

Comment: The nextFireTime is null, in the trigger. why? I am not able to find out this.

Answer (score 0):

I have a found a nice example at https://www.concretepage.com/scheduler/quartz/quartz-2-scheduler-simpletrigger-example-with-simpleschedulebuilder

I have got "some" sample code working OK (I have used .repeatSecondlyForever, as I wanted quick debug output):

```
import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;  
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.SimpleTrigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class SimpleTriggerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException {
         SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
         Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
         JobDetail jobDetail =     JobBuilder.newJob(PrintDateJob.class).withIdentity("goodjob", "mygroup").build();

         SimpleTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("goodjob", "mygroup")
            .startAt(new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 3000))
            .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.repeatSecondlyForever(5))
            .build();

        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
        scheduler.start();

        try {
            //wait to finish the job
            Thread.sleep(200000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //shutdown scheduler gracefully
        scheduler.shutdown(true);
    }
}
```

The "PrintDateJob.class" is here:

```
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.quartz.JobKey;

import java.util.Date;

public class PrintDateJob implements Job {
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
        throws JobExecutionException {
        JobKey jobKey = context.getJobDetail().getKey();
        System.out.println(jobKey+": "+ new Date());
    }
}
```

pom.xml is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>chocksaway</groupId>
        <artifactId>001</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

Running the example gave the following output:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
mygroup.goodjob: Thu Jun 21 15:15:53 BST 2018
mygroup.goodjob: Thu Jun 21 15:15:58 BST 2018
mygroup.goodjob: Thu Jun 21 15:16:03 BST 2018
mygroup.goodjob: Thu Jun 21 15:16:08 BST 2018
```

Comment: this kind of demo works as expected. but when I use that in my actual code implementation, it stop working

Comment: What value do you get for "new Date(row.get(field_Schd_Start_TS).longValue())"?

Comment: It will return a date and time from the database. It will be in long type formate, out of which it will construct date object. the filed in the database contain the value in the format 2018-06-21 14:58:36